# Что идиома программирования RAII думает о динамическом выделении памяти? С++

Tags: c++, raii

Читал про ООП и наткнулся на идиому RAII, в основе которой лежит обязательная инициализация и освобождение памяти. Также там сказано, что идиома RAII запрещает динамически выделять память для объектов наших классов. Но что делать с тяжелыми классами, которые забивают стек и требуют выделения в куче? Что программисты делают в таком случае? Просто закрывают глаза и выделяют память динамически или все же следуют RAII и используют стек?

Comment: *"Также там сказано, что идиома RAII запрещает динамически выделять память для объектов наших классов."* - ничего подобного. RAII не подразумевает обязательное использование стека, а стек вполне может использоваться для динамического выделения памяти.

Comment: @user7860670 вы сказали, что стек может использоваться для динамического выделения памяти. Но разве оператор new выделяет память не в куче?

Comment: Нет, он делегирует выделение памяти глобальной или перегруженной функции аллокации. Использование оператора new говорит о том, что объект имеет dynamic storage duration, а не о том, откуда взялась для него память. С++ - это не C#.

Comment: @user7860670 тогда почему использование оператора new не вызывает переполнение стека, если память выделяется из него?

Comment: *"Использование  оператора new говорит о том, что объект имеет dynamic storage duration, а не о том, откуда взялась для него память"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*в основе которой лежит обязательная инициализация и освобождение памяти* - ну, это слишком сильно сказано... Например, это может быть открытие и закрытие файла. Это все же RAII, а не MAII - Resource, не Memory :)

Ну, а насчет больших классов... Обычно класс с идиомой RAII не такой уж большой - ведь он все может хранить в выделяемой памяти.

Но если даже так - то для этого предусмотрены интеллектуальные указатели, которые просто позволяют применить RAII рекурсивно :)